# How to fix Maintenance Plans backup error "BackupIoRequest::ReportIoError: read failure on backup device ..." in mssql to shared folder

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My backup job in Maintenance Plans has an error (Please check error encountered below) which already 3 days straight.

Job configured as follows:

1. (Step 1): Backup the DBs to a shared folder of Server A
2. (Step 2): If Step 1 Success, It will copy the backups from `Server A` to the shared folder of `Server B`.

As per error from event viewer the error stopped at **Step 1**. I still don't know where the error came from but as per checking the backup created in Server A are all complete which is weird.

Here are my isolation:

1. The shared folder of `Server A` and `Server B` are accessible (tried also the account of SQL services job as a user in windows)

Here is the error found in event viewer:

```
1. BackupIoRequest::ReportIoError: read failure on backup device '\\\Server_A\Shared Folder\Database.bak'. Operating system error 64(The specified network name is no longer available.)."
2. "Package "Backup Databases Directly to Server_A Shared Folder" failed."
3. "SQL Server Scheduled Job 'Backup Databases Directly to Server_A Shared Folder.Subplan_1' (0xD20650B4C8A10F41A130C734D053DB63) - Status: Failed - Invoked on: 2019-08-24 00:00:00 - Message: The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 89 (Backup Databases Directly to Server_A Shared Folder.Subplan_1).  The last step to run was step 1 (Subplan_1).
```

Answer (score 0):

> As per error from event viewer the error stopped at Step 1. I still don't know where the error came from

Usually, when you checking it form SQL Agent history, expand the job and select step 1 so that we can see what causing the that error, information must be printed in message section (bottom):

> "BackupIoRequest::ReportIoError: read failure on backup device '\Server_A\Shared Folder\Database.bak'. Operating system error 64(The specified network name is no longer available.)

In this case, there must be something wrong with path (wrong spelled), or the SQL Server service account (not only SQL Agent service account) doesn't have permissions on the shared folder.

When you say *SERVER-A and SERVER-B can access shared folder*, you might have verified logging in at the server with particular user, so that logged-in user got the permissions on the shared folder, as long as same user is service account user of **SQL Server** then we can assume, SQL Server really have access to shared folder.

Hope, fixing permission issues would resolve the error caused.

However, do you have any issues to directly create a backup on `SERVER-B` shared folder as i feel like we are doing unnecessary additional step.

P.s: I personally, recommend to use custom script for maintenance tasks, especially for backups. [My answer at DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/245835/185080) might helpful in your case for better backup strategy